# Como puedo insertar datos en un bucle hasta una fecha especificada?

Tags: oracle, plsql

> ORA-01841: el valor (completo) del año debe estar entre -4713 y +9999, y no 
>   debe ser igual a 0
>   ORA-06512: en línea 8

```
DECLARE 
   LIMITE DATE := '30-01-2018';
   CONTADOR NUMBER(2) := 0;
   ACTUAL DATE := SYSDATE;
BEGIN
   LOOP
            CONTADOR := CONTADOR + 1;
            ACTUAL := ACTUAL + CONTADOR;
            INSERT INTO STK_COTIZACION(COT_FEC, COT_MON, COT_TASA) VALUES 
(ACTUAL, 1, 5800);
            EXIT WHEN ACTUAL <= '30-01-2018';
   END LOOP;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CONTADOR: ' || TO_CHAR(CONTADOR) || ' ACTUAL: ' || 
TO_CHAR(ACTUAL));
END;
```

Comment: no funciona que quiere decir? que es lo que pasa?

Comment: Necesito insertar el mismo registro hasta la fecha LIMITE que declare en el codigo pero me lanza un error. "ORA-01841: el valor (completo) del año debe estar entre -4713 y +9999, y no debe ser igual a 0
ORA-06512: en línea 8"

Comment: Ese error deberia estar escrito en la pregunta. Por favor mira [ask]

Comment: ahhh esta mal la condicion!!!! si le pones que actual sea menor al 30/01, no va a cortar nunca porque esa es justamente la condicion de entrada...

Comment: Ya me inserta, pero no me suma las fechas, inserta la fecha actual + 1 y termina ahi, lo que yo quiero es que siga insertando hasta que alcance el LIMITE

Comment: No se entiende. Porque no se cual es la fecha hasta donde queres que llegue.. ni la fecha que te esta tomando como actual, ni como esta quedando tu tabla.

Comment: ACTUAL : SYSDATE que seria en este caso 27/12/2018, cuando lo sumo con el CONTADOR es 28/12/2018 y yo quiero que repita este proceso hasta que ACTUAL sea mayor a LIMITE que es 30/01/2019.

Comment: Disculpa, mi error esta en que puse 2018 al limite, tendria que ser 2019

Answer (score 1):

Estimado

Te sugiero usar un ciclo while en el loop, te adjunto ejemplo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_FECHAS IS

BEGIN
    DECLARE 
       LIMITE DATE := '28-02-2019';
       CONTADOR INT := 1;
       ACTUAL DATE := SYSDATE;
    BEGIN

    WHILE ACTUAL <= LIMITE
       LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CONTADOR: ' || TO_CHAR(CONTADOR) || ' ACTUAL: ' || TO_CHAR(ACTUAL));
            /* Codigo de Insert, update o delete aquí */
            ACTUAL := ACTUAL + 1;
            CONTADOR := CONTADOR + 1;
       END LOOP;
    END;
END TEST_FECHAS;
```

En este caso solo uso "contador" porque lo declaraste pero no lo mezclo con "actual", ya que así no avanzas día a día, sino que vas saltándote los días 01-02-04-07-11 etc ¿Entiendes?.